# ember js variable binding

Tags: ember.js, data-binding, controller

Ember version: 2.18.0

URL: http://localhost:4200/bands/

/templates/bands.hbs

```
{{input type="text" class="new-band" placeholder="New Band" value=name}}
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm new-band-button" onclick={{action "createBand"}}>Add</button>
```

/controllers/bands.js

```
export default Controller.extend({
  name: 'abc',

  actions: {
    createBand: function(){
      var name = this.get('name');
    }
  }
});
```

On startup, the input will have the value 'abc' as defined in the controller.

But in the action, the name returned is still 'abc' whatever I typed in.

Any thoughts?

Comment: how do you know what `var name` is? Do you `console.log(name)` it? again: https://ember-twiddle.com/95a5760d0a8876030a38f53e19709d61?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.application.hbs

Comment: there must be something wrong either in your routes, in your controllers, whereever. The examples you give are working as expected.

Comment: @Jeff I put a break point in the Chrome debugger and it shows me that this.get('name') is still 'abc'. This one fires the action though because I changed {{action "createBand"}} to onclick={{action "createBand"}} in my 1st question.